# Introspection of messages generated in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is there any way to get at the actual messages generated during the evaluation of an expression in Mathematica? Say I'm numerically solving an ODE and it blows up, like so

```
In[1] := sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -15 x[t], x[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 1}, 
                       Method -> "ExplicitEuler"];
```

In this case, I'll get the `NDSolve::mxst` error, telling me the maximum number of 10000 steps was reached at `t == 0.08671962566152185`. Now, if I look at the `$MessageList` variable, I only receive the message name; in particular, the information about the value of `t` where `NDSolve` decided to quit has been lost.

Now, I can always get that information from `sol` using the `InterpolatingFunctionDomain` function from one of the standard add-on packages, but if I can somehow pull it out of the message, it would be quite helpful.

Comment: Strongly related: ["Seeing truncated messages in Mathematica"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264734/seeing-truncated-messages-in-mathematica).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to use $MessagePrePrint to set up a function which would store away each of the messages for later retrieval.

Comment: So far this looks like the best bet. The documentation for `$MessagePrePrint` suggests using `Sow`/`Reap` for that purpose.

Comment: I tried the `Sow`/`Reap` solution with `$MessagePrePrint`. It worked OK, but ultimately I found introspecting the returned `InterpolatingFunction` objects was considerably less cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will work, but if the only thing you want to know are the values of specific parameters at the point of error then a kludgy way of getting them would be to define those variables with dummy values globally. This works with loop counters, but I don't know if it works from within `NDSolve`. Another kludge would be to make t [Dynamic](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dynamic.html) and have an evaluated cell with t.

A more elegant (and probably the correct) approach would be to use [Reap](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reap.html) and [Sow](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sow.html).