# Seeing truncated messages in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is it possible to see full version of a `Message` that got truncated? IE, I see something along the lines of `0.105309,0.394682,<<20>>,<<20>>,<<20>>,0.394631` in the `Messages` window. I'm guessing `<<20>>` represents omitted parts, how do I get the whole thing?

The function called is FindMaximum on a problem with 50 variables.

**Update:**
Simon's answer seems to work for general messages, also I found an approach that's specific to capturing the FindMaximum "not a real number" message.

To get the point which causes FindMaximum to fail with "not a real number" message you can do the following (redefining `Message` is the only approach I could find because the point doesn't get passed to `EvaluationMonitor` or `StepMonitor`)

```
Unprotect[Message];
Message[FindMaximum::"nrnum", args___] := (captured = {args}; 
   Print["Captured FindMaximum::nrnum at ", First[{args}]]);
{badvals, badvars, badobj} = ReleaseHold[captured];
```

Comment: I don't think that it saves messages that are turned off (at least not those that use the `Off[]` mechanism). See my comments below.

Comment: @Simon Undocumented function ``Internal`HandlerBlock`` allows to catch messages that are turned off. See my answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can recover a long message that has already been generated. As `$MessageList` and `Message[]` only store the message names, not the arguments passed to them.

To stop `Short[]` from being automatically applied to messages you can `Unset[$MessagePrePrint]`. It's default value is `Automatic` -- whatever that entails.

---

Rather than print long messages all the time, it might be better to use something like

```
General::longmsg="A long message (`1`) was produced. The full message has been saved in `2`";
$MessagePrePrint=With[{bc=ByteCount[#]},If[bc>65536,
  With[{fn=FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory,StringJoin["MmaMsg",ToString/@DateList[]]}]},
    Put[#,fn];Message[General::longmsg,bc,Row[{fn}]];Short[Shallow[#],1]],
  #]]&;
```

This will print out the message as normal unless the `ByteCount` is too large ( > 65536) in which case it will print out two messages: The first informs you that a large message was produced and gives you the file where it was saved. The second is the truncated version of the full message.

Comment: I was going to suggest $MessagePrePrint too. Seems the way to go.

Comment: This is great, even platform independent, definitely going into my toolbox

Comment: By the way, it seems MessagePrePrint is called even for message that aren't printed. I ended up with hundreds of files because some LinearAlgebra subroutine called from FindMaximum calls MessagePrePrint with 100x100 dense matrices as input. I'm guessing you don't normally see them because this message is turned off

Comment: The messages can't be turned off. You can test this using my above code and running `Off[General::argx]; Message[General::argx, 1, Range[1000]]` which prints no message and generates no file. It must be something else.

Comment: In fact you can check that if the message is `Off` then `$MessagePrePrint` is not even called. Just set `$MessagePrePrint = (Print["hi there"]) &;` and call various `On` and `Off` messages.

Comment: Oh, I think you are right, this may be a consequence of me trying both yours and Andrew Moylan's answer at the same time, and I can't reproduce it again

Answer (score 2):

I'm not in front of the right computer right now, so I can't test it for sure... But I think you can fully customize the message handling behavior with something like:

```
Block[{Message = f}, ...]
```

For example you might use

```
f[args___] := Print[{args}];
```

Again, not in front of Mathematica right now. Please feel free to wiki edit this answer.

Comment: This seems to capture messages which aren't normally output into Messages window

Answer (score 2):

Undocumented function `` Internal`HandlerBlock `` ([uncovered](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/msg/d9b16db8f5acb222) by Maxim Rytin) is applicable here:

```
Off[FindMaximum::"nrnum"]
Internal`HandlerBlock[{"Message", Print}, 
 Message[FindMaximum::"nrnum", arg1, arg2, arg3]]
(* => Hold[Message[FindMaximum::nrnum,arg1,arg2,arg3],False]*)
```

> Another handler type is "MessageTextFilter". "Message" is invoked for
>   every generated message and passes one argument of the form Hold[...,
>   ...] to the handler function, with the second element set to False for
>   quieted messages. "MessageTextFilter" is invoked for messages that
>   actually get printed and calls the function with three arguments.
>
> Maxim Rytin

---

Another possibility is to modify `$MessagePrePrint` in such a way that it will print messages containing in-line cells with truncated arguments which can be expanded to full arguments on evaluation. It can be done with `Interpretation`:

```
truncatingRules = {lst : {x_, y__} /; 
     MatrixQ[lst, NumberQ] && Length[lst] > 3 :>
    {x /. v : {a_, b__} /; Length[v] > 3 :>
       {a, 
        Interpretation[Style[Skeleton[Length[{b}]], Gray], 
         Sequence @@ {b}]},
     Interpretation[Style[Skeleton[Length[{y}]], Gray], 
      Sequence @@ {y}]},
   lst : {x_, y__} /; VectorQ[lst, NumberQ] && Length[lst] > 3 :>
    {x, Interpretation[Style[Skeleton[Length[{y}]], Gray], 
      Sequence @@ {y}]}};

InlineCellInsideMessage[expr_] := 
 Style[DisplayForm[
   Cell[BoxData[MakeBoxes[expr, StandardForm]], "Input"]], 
  FontWeight -> Bold, FontFamily -> "Courier", Background -> Yellow, 
  FontColor -> Red, FontSize -> 12, StripOnInput -> True, 
  AutoNumberFormatting -> True, ShowStringCharacters -> True]

$MessagePrePrint = 
 Function[expr, 
  If[TrueQ[ByteCount[Unevaluated[expr]] < $OutputSizeLimit/20.], 
   InlineCellInsideMessage[expr],
   InlineCellInsideMessage[expr /. truncatingRules]
   ]]
```

Of course, the above version of `$MessagePrePrint` is just a draft but it illustrates the main idea.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [this link](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5/TheMathematicaBook/APracticalIntroductionToMathematica/AlgebraicCalculations/1.4.8.html):

"When you do symbolic calculations, it is quite easy to end up with extremely complicated expressions. Often, you will not even want to see the complete result of a computation."

You can control your display using `Short`.

`Short[%, n]` will display `n` lines of your previous result, so that could be what you need.

More info [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ControllingTheDisplayOfLargeExpressions.html).

Comment: I don't see how to use that to get stuff that went into the message window

Comment: @Yaroslav: ok, what kind of command did you execute to get result you described?

Comment: FindMaximum. Note, that I'm talking about Messages, not the output of the command

Comment: @Yaroslav: ah, now your question is clearer. Sorry, can't help you right now because I don't have Mathematica installed...